# Display List Of files in grid using .net mvc razor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My Controller code

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
      DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Documents\New folder");
      List<FileInfo> files = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.pdf").ToList();
      return View(files);
    }
```

My ViewCode is

```
@model IEnumerable<FileInfo>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
 }

@foreach (FileInfo file in Model)
{
  <li>@file.Name</li>
  <li>@file.Extension</li>
}
```

Here I need to display these list of files in a grid along with its hyperlink as an image.

Any suggestions are appreciated thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like below code but I suggest to use any jquery library for grid like jqgrid..

```
<table class="grid">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Extension</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    { 

        <tr>
            <td class="left">@item.Name</td>
            <td class="left">@item.Extension</td>
            <td>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = item.ID })">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Image.bmp")", alt="Edit" /></a>
            </td>
        </tr>   
    }
</table>
```